# USB Serial Communication slow on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspberry-pi, serial-port, usb, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I posted a similar question last week but there was something wrong in my code that I (think) I have fixed now.

I have a device sending 80x80 16 bits images through USB (cdc-acm) at a framerate of 10 fps.

To get those images, I wrote some code that I tested on a Ubuntu Laptop, and also on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B.

The code works fine (meaning I get the right images) on both devices, but on the Raspberry Pi, the framerate is very low !! I only get up to 5 fps maximum.

The part of the code that is reading the images from the serial port runs in a seperated thread than the main program. In the mean time the "CPU Usage Monitor" of the raspberry Pi (running Raspbian Desktop) is showing me that only around 20% (sometimes up to 31%) of the CPU is used so there should be still some processing power available under the hood, am I right ?

Does anybody knows where the problem can come from ?

As it might come from the way I handle the serial communication part in my code, the code below shows how I do it. Note that as I was suggested in my previous post, I tried to play with different Baud rates, it doesn't change anything at all.

```
/// INITIALISATION

// Try to open the serial port
int m_file_descriptor = open("/dev/ttyACM0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY /*| O_NDELAY*/);
// Failed to open
if (m_file_descriptor == -1)
{
    std::cerr << "Unable to open serial port" << std::endl;
}
// If success, configure serial like expected
else
{ 
    fcntl(m_file_descriptor, F_SETFL, 0);

    struct termios settings;
    tcgetattr(m_file_descriptor, &settings);  // Get current default settings
    cfmakeraw(&settings);  // Raw serial communication (custom bytes sending and parsing)
    //cfsetspeed(&settings, B115200); // Setting baud rates doesn't change anything

    // Now clean and set params
    tcflush( m_file_descriptor, TCIFLUSH );
    tcsetattr( m_file_descriptor, TCSANOW, &settings );
}


/// Getting Data : main loop of the serial com thread

unsigned char read_buffer[128];

while (m_isListening)
{
    int rd = read(m_file_descriptor, read_buffer, 128); // Blocking read

    // Octets were read
    if (rd > 0)
    {
        /// Processing read_buffer basically copy the pixels' octets into a class member image data buffer
    }
    else if (rd == 0)
    {
        std::cout << "No bytes read" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%d %s \n", errno, strerror(errno));
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

Based on comments, it might come from the USB speed being limited to USB 1.1 speed on the Raspberry Pi.

On the raspberry Pi, the first line returned of `dmesg` command when I plug the device is:

`usb 1-1.4: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg`

Whereas on the Ubuntu laptop it is:

`usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd`

I don't know much about **dwc_otg** and **xhci_hcd** but I suppose the problem is here... Anyone has an idea?

**EDIT 2 :**

Apparently the USB speed problem (in particular speed repartition with un common devices) is common on Raspberry Pi. I found a workaround that seemed to make my device work at 10 fps:

I added : `dwc_otg.speed=1` to the file `/boot/cmdline.txt`. According to what I found on the internet, this will limit USB speed to full speed 12Mbps (USB 1.1).

This increased the framerate of my device, but the problem is that with line, the mouse and keyboard plugged to the Raspberry don't respond anymore.

Comment: have you tried using a read buffer larger than 128 bytes?

Comment: @GarrGodfrey yes I tried that. The thing is that the read is always returning 128 bytes or less (so for parsing purpose I am sticking to that).

Comment: interesting you are getting about 64kB/s, which is the USB 1.1 interrupt data limit, but Pi3 has USB2.0 so you should get much faster.

Comment: @GarrGodfrey interesting indeed!! this sounds like something I should configure somewhere.

Comment: could be coincidence. Do you need to open in READ/WRITE?  Try what speed you get with: dd of=/dev/zero if=/dev/ttyACM0 bs=14403 count=60

Comment: @GarrGodfrey Yes I also need write to send start and stop commands to the device (4 bytes for each command). The output of your command gave me:
dd: warning: partial read (128 bytes); suggest iflag=fullblock so I ran it with this flag.

864180 bytes copied, 8.04 s, 107 kB/s

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but it seems to me that an 80x80 16-bit image would use 102400 bits.  At 115200bps you would be able to get 1.125fps across that link.  And that's assuming no overhead (which there's at least 10% on an async serial link for start and stop bits).  What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @MichaelBurr the calculation is correct I don't understand either why I can get 5 fps on the RasPi and 10 on Ubuntu  laptop.

Comment: I don't really know anything about cdc-acm (today is the first I've heard of it), but from some googling around it seems that if the MCU doesn't interface through an actual UART (ie., it's implementing it's side of the channel direct-to-USB) then the baud rate setting is irrelevant.  However, I didn't find clear information on this, so it might be completely a misunderstanding on my part.  That doesn't help with your problem, but it might explain why you're able to exceed the specified baud rate (and why different baud rates don't change anything for you).

Comment: @MichaelBurr Thank you very much for these useful information. I found out the problem comes from USB speed repartition by RaspBian OS.

Comment: You're welcome, but I have my doubts that I was really any help.  I don't even know what "USB speed repartition" is!  But I see you've updated your post with some information about it.